# How to correctly set up Tracd behind Nginx?

Tags: nginx, trac

Running `tracd` and accessing its web directly works fine.

However, I want it sitting behind nginx, accessible by going to `example.com/trac/`.

To that end, I've made the following change to the nginx configuration:

```
location /trac/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3456/; # tracd listens there
    proxy_redirect default;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Visiting `example.com/trac/` now shows me a broken Trac homepage, where none of the CSS, JS or image files get loaded because all of those other requests get sent to something like `example.com/css`, instead of `example.com/trac/css`.

How can I fix this?

How do I make Trac realize it's in `example.com/trac/`, and not `example.com/`?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I've set the following `trac.ini` settings and restarted `tracd`, but the problem persists:

```
base_url = https://example.com/trac/
use_base_url_for_redirect = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems defining `base_url` and `use_base_url_for_redirect` no longer works.

Instead, use the `--base-path` option when running `tracd` directly.

So now I run `tracd` like this:

```
tracd /path/to/trac/dir --base-path=trac
```

And the nginx conf becomes simpler:

```
location /trac/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3456/trac/;
    proxy_redirect default;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

This seems to work.